# Set fields in Structure HTML with PHP7

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

I have a problem for setting field in htlm5 with results query.

```
{
    $query = "SELECT nome,cognome FROM utente";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        print_r($rows);
    };
}
```

How can I take this result in this structure?

```
<tr>
  <td>??? field 1</td>
  <td>??? field 2</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, $rows is just an array that contains the fields you request in your query, so you can access its fields by using the index.

```
<?php
$rows = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
mysqli_fetch_all($rows,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$html_string = "<table> <thead>....whatever optional... </thead> <tbody>";
foreach( $rows as $r){
  $html_string .= "<tr> <td>" . $r[0] . "</td><td>" . $r[1] . "</td></tr>";
}
$html_string .= "</tbody></table>";
echo $html_string; 
?>
```

Should be enough for the rows of your table.

Comment: Thank you!!! Another question, if I have a bootstrap structure in html5, i must put this structure inside the foreach in echo?

Comment: no, you don't want the tag <table> to be repeated for each row... you should put your echo "<table>" righ before the foreach. let me edit the answer, maybe you can accept it.

Comment: Did you notice that MYSQLI_ASSOC thing in your code? How do you think what it could be for?

Comment: just tried to be of some help, even though it was pretty easy... i can even delete the answer if needed.

Comment: No need to delete but it would be nice if you make it consistent

Comment: hope it is correct now. sorry for the mistake.